# Acceder a un arreglo Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

no se como acceder a este tipo de arreglo, poniendo en la vista `dd($pedido);` recibo lo siguiente:

```
"[{"idpedido":"T-202010096","total":484,"fecha":"19\/7\/2020","estado":0,"metodo":"Transferencia bancaria","factura":null,"created_at":"2020-07-19 17:38:34","Pro ▶"
```

No se diferenciar el arreglo y no se como acceder a el, he probado de estos modos;

`{{ $pedido['idpedido' }}` y así `{{ $pedido->idpedido }}` pero sin éxito.

Consulta:

```
$pedido = DB::table('orders')
                    ->select('idpedido', DB::raw('SUM(total) as total'), 'fecha', 'estado', 'metodo', 'factura', 'created_at')
                    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
                    ->selectRaw("GROUP_CONCAT(producto) AS Productos ")
                    ->where('id_cliente', auth()->user()->id)
                    ->groupBy('idpedido', 'fecha', 'estado', 'metodo', 'factura', 'created_at')
                    ->take(1)
                    ->get();
```

Me devuelve: `Undefined variable: idpedido`

Cabe decir que esta consulta la paso para enviar un mail con la info:

```
Mail::to('el mail')->send(new PedidoNuevo($pedido));
```

Luego en la clase PedidoNuevo:

```
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject = 'Nuevo pedido - Camas y Literas';

    public $pedido;

    public function __construct($pedido)
    {
        $this->pedido = $pedido;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.pedidoNuevo');
    }
```

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta @BetaM

Comment: Si esos datos los gasto en una vista y me funciona bien, pero esto es para mandarlo por mail, mira la pregunta que la amplie más, si solo obtengo el último resultado @BetaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observaciones:

- Según veo después de agrupar y ordenar solo buscas obtener un valor, por tanto esta demás usar el método `get()` que te haría obtener el resultado como una colección de objetos
- Si como menciono solo es un valor el que deseas después de ordenar, entonces no tiene caso usar el método `take()` en cambio usa el método `first()` y quita el método `get()`

De modo que tu resultado sea un objeto de esta forma:

```
{"clave1":"valor1","clave2":valor2}
```

Así evitarás tener que iterar los valores y en cambio podrás consultarlos de esta manera:

```
{{ $variable->propiedad }}
```

Entonces trata de construir tu consulta así:

```
$pedido = DB::table('orders')
                    ->select('idpedido', DB::raw('SUM(total) as total'), 'fecha', 'estado', 'metodo', 'factura', 'created_at')
                    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
                    ->selectRaw("GROUP_CONCAT(producto) AS Productos ")
                    ->where('id_cliente', auth()->user()->id)
                    ->groupBy('idpedido', 'fecha', 'estado', 'metodo', 'factura', 'created_at')
                    ->first();
```

- Ahora si planeas dejar la consulta como esta, entonces tendrías que iterar los valores aunque solo te esta regresando un registro

Comment: Perfecto eres un grande como siempre @BetaM ;) gracias!

Comment: Una pregunta @BetaM , puedo enviar el mail a dos destinatarios distintos?

Comment: Lo siento, mi experiencia con Laravel no llega al tema de emails